# Loop in shell script

Tags: shell

Hi
I did a script in shell which read a file with some data inside:

```
for (( read x x Y ))
do
if ["$Y" == "5,"]; then
    echo "5"
    sed -i '/^[0-9][0-9]*, [0-9][0-9]*, 6,/d' file.txt  
else 
    echo 'fail'
    fi
done
```

when I did it with a while loop it works but too long because the file is very big and do it line by line
so I would like to do it with a loop for and I get this error: `syntax error near unexpected token 'done'`

Can you help me?
Thanks

EDIT : I would like to know if it's possible to do something like this:
 `awk 'BEGIN {FS=", "}`
        `{ if ( $3 == "5" )'`
            `echo "5"` 
            `sed -i '/^[0-9][0-9]*, [0-9][0-9]*, 6,/d' newfile` 
        `'else { print "fail" } }' file`

Comment: You only have one file to read , and that is `file.txt` correct?, so the for loop actually is reading `file.txt` correct? If so, then when "5," is detected, you would have already deleted those lines using `sed`. On subsequent detection of "5," , there will be no lines to delete. but you will still be callling `sed`. That's your overhead. show a clearer example of your script (don't show it halfway) and show any input files and expected output.

Comment: Note that `[` is a command, so it requires a space after it: `if [ "$Y" = "5," ]; then ...; fi`. Shell syntax is not really C-like.

Answer (score 2):

There are several syntax errors in your code.

Try this:

```
while read x x Y
do
  if [ "$Y" == "5," ]
  then
    echo "5"
    sed -i '/^[0-9][0-9]*, [0-9][0-9]*, 6,/d' file.txt  
  else
    echo 'fail'
  fi
done < YOUR_FILE
```

YOUR_FILE should have at least three columns (`x x Y`).

Comment: thanks, now I have no error but when I run my script nothing happened

Comment: I updated my answer. This code snippet should work if your file has three columns and you're looking for "5," in the third column. If it doesn't work, show us more of your code.

Comment: the file have more than 3 columns

Comment: OK, I edited the answer. It should have *at least* three columns. `x x Y` are the first three columns.

Comment: @Glist: using a `while` loop with `read` is idiomatic shell script.  It is aconventional to read both the first two columns into the same variable; you would normally use `read junk x y` (using three different names, and keeping the case consistent - upper-case for environment variables, and lower-case for non-environment variables).  Classically, double-equals was an error; it generally works these days.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Good, knowledgeable comment. I wanted to keep as much of Glist's code, yet make it a Bash script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the `if` statement with `fi` before `done`.

You can do it in AWK too, without the loop:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="<SET YOUR FIELD SEPARATOR HERE>"}
     { if ( $3 == "5" ) { print "5" ; if ( $0 !~ "^[0-9][0-9]*, [0-9][0-9]*, 6,") print $0 >> "tmpfile" } else { print "fail" ; print $0 >> "tmpfile" } }' YOUR_INPUT_FILE
```

Then see the contents of tmpfile...

HTH

Comment: awk works good, it print 5 or fail but nothing change in the file, this : $0 !~ "^[0-9][0-9]*, [0-9][0-9]*, 6,") print $0 >> "file.txt" it's not executed, do you know why?

Comment: Maybe you are using the same output file as you input?

Answer (score 0):

If you start an `if` in a shell script then you should also end it with `fi`

Comment: How does your answer differ from that of Zsolt Botykai?